# Android: Is it possible to create a media file using openFileOutput function

Tags: android, file

I had created files i.e., txt files and stored values into it using openFileOutput fn. This function creates the txt file in the data/data/app_name/files folder.. Now i am trying to save a media files like .mp3 file to that data/data/app-name folder.. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in advance.

```
fOut = openFileOutput("a.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);



                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

                    String aa="hi";

                    osw.write(aa);

                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close();
```

This is how i had written a file to the data/data/app-name folder.. Nw i am trying to write a mp3 file but the osw.write(aa) accepts  string or char array..

Comment: Cant you just use the ending .mp3 to the file? Just be aware that the file has to contain some sort of metadata for the mediaplayer to understand it.

Comment: I can do like that but write fn for openFileOutpu object accepts string or char array? i dont knw how to covert fileoutputstream to string or char array

Comment: you tried and you asked because what ?

Answer (score 4):

`Context.openFileOutput()` ([reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)) creates a `FileOutputStream` object which is capable of writing binary data (see [write()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method), so the answer is Yes, it can be used to write media files.

Comment: @Deepak Here are some examples of writing binary using `FileOutputStream`: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=245 + http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/ + http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter09/fileBinaryIO.html

Comment: i knw Fileoutputstream can write bytes, but i am dealing with openFileOutput which has OutputStreamWriter similar to Fileoutputstream but the write fn is different.. Plz check

Comment: @Deepak Sorry I don't understand what you mean.  Please update your question with more detail.

Comment: @Deepak OK, just don't create the `OutputStreamWriter` and write to the `FileOutputStream` directly.  You are right; `OutputStreamWriter` deals with strings and characters only.